# Calling .wait() on subprocess breaks the script I'm calling in the subprocess

Tags: python, syntaxnet, parsey-mcparseface

thanks for taking the time to read this post. Basically I'm trying to call syntaxnet's parsey mcparseface from a subprocess. For some reason it wont run unless I change the working directory. I can run the subprocess with the following.

```
process = subprocess.Popen("./syntaxnet/demo.sh", cwd="/home/kahless/models/syntaxnet")
```

The problem is I also need my script to wait until parsey finishes. So I tried to use the wait command

```
process.wait()
```

But for some reason when using .wait() or .communicate() parsey mcparseface wont complete correctly.

Comment: but when you do not `.wait()` or `.communicate()` it does work? Are you sure it is just not working and you only notice it when waiting for it to finish?

Comment: Yea I know that it works because there is information being printed in the console and when I try .wait() it shows that it did not complete correctly. Is it possible that the .wait() command changes my cwd?

Comment: What console is being printed to? Does python "show that it did not complete correctly." or something else? I'd expect there to be no output without specifying `stdout` and `stderr` to the `Popen` constructor.

Comment: Sorry when I said console I meant terminal. When running demo.sh it prints output to the terminal it is running in.

Comment: When I run demo.sh as a subprocess that same info is being printed to the terminal.

Comment: Here's a link to the demo.sh code https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/syntaxnet/syntaxnet/demo.sh

Comment: Are you asking if there is a python error code. If so there is not. The info being printed is coming from syntaxnet